# Chino como forma cariñosa de llamar a un perro?

Tags: coloquialismos, neologismos

Un alumno, en busca de una expresión o uso novedoso u original, *pero no inventado*, me presenta la palabra "chino" para referirse a un perro.

El ejemplo que utiliza es: "Debidamente entrenado el chino, te da la patita y todo."

Yo no he escuchado o leído esa manera de referirse a los perros, a diferencia de chucho, quiltro, y otros más o menos despectivos, y me gustaría conocer si algún hispanohablante la ha escuchado en conversaciones coloquiales.

Comment: Curioso. DLE nos explica que _perro/a chino/a_ es 1. m. y f. perro que carece completamente de pelo y tiene las orejas pequeñas y rectas, el hocico pequeño y puntiagudo y el cuerpo grueso y de color oscuro.

Comment: Suena un poco como un xoloitzcuintle.

Comment: nunca he escuchado ello y me suena a despectivo. Recomiendo no usarlo

Answer (score 1):

Sí, yo he escuchado referirse a un perro como chino. Creo que es una distorsión del francés *chien*, jugando un poco con las pronunciaciones es fácil pasar de *chien* a chino.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).